# Getting a value into POST or GET from a form with Select and Option Values

Tags: html, post, get

So I have this list of option values, and I want a user to be able to select any item on the drop down list and submit it, and this will delete a record (I have a custom Python script that will do it).

Anyway, how do I send, say

```
<form action="delete.psp" method="get">
<select>
<option value="id=1">1</option>
<option value="id=2">2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I am trying to send numeric information to the script - should I switch id=1, etc to simply 1? Would this work?

To be clear, I am trying to send the data as the variable id inside of get, with the value of 1, 2, etc.

Comment: For reference: ["HTML Controls"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.2) and ["The SELECT, OPTGROUP, and OPTION elements"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6), noting that "name" is defined on `<select>` while "value" is defined on `<option>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to give your select a `name` so that the browser knows what to send it to the server as. (Also: you need a submit button unless you're doing it in code.)

```
<form action="delete.psp" method="get">
<select name="blah">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Personally I would just set `value="1"`

Comment: Aditional "blah" will be the get data and the selected value as value

Comment: Yep, I just figured this out on my own like 15 seconds ago, before checking here. Thanks! I will still select your answer.